# MySQL: Order by field, placing empty cells at end

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have a MySQL table which contains a number of products. What I want to do is sort the table by one particular column (most of the values begin with numbers for example: 1st, 2nd), etc. However, since some records do not have a value for this column, when I try to sort, the table automatically puts empty rows FIRST.

I am looking for a way to sort the row ASCENDING, but only insert blank records at the end of the sorted records, if that makes sense?

Any help would be most gratefully received!

Answer (score 95, accepted):

```
select * from table
order by if(field = '' or field is null,1,0),field
```

Comment: @BenM: If @nick's answer solved your problem, you should accept it. @Nick: +1.

Comment: Another quick question for you if I could?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825875/mysql-sort-1st-before-101st

Comment: @Ken White - I have to wait 2 minutes longer before I can accept Nick's answer...

Comment: A bit simpler: `ORDER BY IF (\`field\` <> '', 0, 1)` ASC;  Also, be careful when using a function in the `ORDER BY` clause; MySQL cannot use an index in these cases.  These queries will work fine on "small" tables but will slow down drastically as your project scales in size.

Answer (score 17):

This is one of the most effective method

**ASC Order**

```
SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY name IS NULL, name ASC
```

**Expected Result:**

```
+----+--------+------------+
| id |  name  | date_login |
+----+--------+------------+
|  3 |  david | 2016-12-24 |
|  2 |  john  | NULL       |
|  4 |  zayne | 2017-03-02 |
|  1 |  NULL  | 2017-03-12 |
```

**DESC Order**

```
SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY name IS NULL, name DESC
```

**Expected Result:**

```
+----+--------+------------+
| id |  name  | date_login |
+----+--------+------------+
|  4 |  zayne | 2017-03-02 |
|  2 |  john  | NULL       |
|  3 |  david | 2016-12-24 |
|  1 |  NULL  | 2017-03-12 |
```

Comment: This works correctly and is the easiest way for NULL values, but doesn't work on empty string values.

Comment: If you need to test for both NULL and an empty string, you can do `ORDER BY name IS NOT TRUE, name DESC`