# Sort multiple text fields in MYSQL according to information entered or not

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have a expert table with fields like `expert_description`, `company_description`, `expert_website`, `expert_email`, `company_website`.

These fields are not required, so they may be `NULL`.

When searching the tables, entries with most non-`NULL` fields should come first.

For example, there are four users:

1. user1 : who had entered info for all 5 fields
2. user2 : who had entered info for only 1 fields
3. user3 : who had entered info for only 4 fields
4. user4 : who had entered info for only 3 fields

The result should be

1. user1
2. user3
3. user4
4. user2

Comment: What SQL have you tried?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825804/mysql-order-by-field-placing-empty-cells-at-end

Comment: I tried char_length function on fields but it didn't worked as my expectations.

Comment: May i ask why my 2 reputation point is deducted. Let me know my mistake so i can take care of it in future.

Comment: I suspect it is the fact that your question lacked any attempt at SQL code.

Comment: No i tried lot and also googled so many times but may be my searching keyword was not matching to my exact requirement. I also searched on this site but didn't get any solutions that's why at last i think to ask it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

```
select * from table
order by if(field = '' or field is null,1,0),field
```

got this answer from the link suggested by @Rossco

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create a field in the user table that will store the count of fields filled.

This column should be updated every time the user adds/remove a field.

Then you simply can order by the "fieldcount" column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this, if the values of your empty fields are NULL.

```
SELECT expert_description, company_description, expert_website, expert_email, company_website, 
((expert_description IS NULL) + (company_description IS NULL) + (expert_website IS NULL) + (expert_email IS NULL) + (company_website IS NULL)) AS empty_count 
FROM experts 
WHERE 1 
ORDER BY empty_count;
```

[IS NULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-null) will return `1` if the value of the field is `NULL` else it will return `0`.

Comment: Hi @Vivek, you logic is correct but it throws error, please consider some changes: `SELECT expert_description, company_description, expert_website, expert_email, company_website, 
( (expert_description IS NULL) + (company_description IS NULL) + (expert_website IS NULL) + (expert_email IS NULL) + (company_website IS NULL) ) AS empty_count 
FROM experts 
ORDER BY empty_count;`. Just add brackets and change order. :)

Comment: Thanks for rectifying! Edited my answer.

Comment: You forgot the ORDER again :)

Answer (score 0):

use this query:

```
SELECT user FROM your_table 
ORDER BY expert_description DESC, company_description DESC, 
expert_website DESC, expert_email DESC, company_website DESC;
```

Thank you.