# mysql join issue when one of the values is not assigned

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have the issue of getting the records out of database in the specific condintion.  I have table 'test' I want to get the listing from sorted by driverid and table 'drivers' which i use to adjust sorting of the listing from 'test' table.

My query:

```
SELECT * FROM test JOIN drivers ON test.driverid=drivers.driverid ORDER BY queno
```

Table 'drivers' looks like:

```
driver | driverid | queno
-------------------
drv1   | 15       | 3
drv2   | 30       | 1
drv3   | 40       | 2
```

Problem is when there is no value assigned to 'driverid' in 'test' table then these results are listed at very beginning. I would like to have these listed at the end

How to achieve that? Thx in advance!

Comment: Use full outer join. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join

Comment: **I'm sorry i had some testing issue and had to adjust essence of the question**

Comment: **when there is no value assigned to 'driverid' in 'test' table then these results are listed at very beginning**. You are sure? If `test` is not assigned to a `driver`, the driver should be not in the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the working solution elswhere:

[MySQL: Order by field, placing empty cells at end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825804/mysql-order-by-field-placing-empty-cells-at-end)

```
SELECT * FROM test JOIN drivers ON test.driverid=drivers.driverid ORDER BY if(queno = '' or queno is null,1,0), queno
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make **driver.driverid** primary key (PK) and **test.driverid** foreign key (FK) and enforce data integrity. This will also eliminate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Place a minus sign (-) before the column name and switch the ASC to DESC  or DESC to ASC order (opposite to what you want).

**try this:-**

```
SELECT * FROM test JOIN drivers ON test.driverid=drivers.driverid ORDER BY -queno DESC;
```

**Note:-** While this may work well for numbers and dates, it may not be the best solution to sort fields with alpha or alphanumeric values